# how to make a axe throw and return sistem in unity

Tags: c

guys,

so, i'm trying to make a game similar to the god of war in the unit, but i don't know how to make the ax return dynamically, eustou trying to make it come back without problems, but i still couldn't get a satisfactory result, i'm using an Animation to make the ax rotates and when it gets close enough to the player, the script deactivates the Animator and a Quaternion.Slerp Corrects the rotation of the ax, This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class AxeController : MonoBehaviour {

    // The axe object
    public Rigidbody axe;
    // Amount of force to apply when throwing
    public float throwForce = 50;
    // the target; which is the player's hand.
    public Transform target;
    // The middle point between the axe and the player's hand, to give it a curve
    public Transform curve_point;
    public Transform hand;
    // Last position of the axe before returning it, to use in the Bezier Quadratic Curve formula
    private Vector3 old_pos;
    // Is the axe returning? To update the calculations in the Update method
    private bool isReturning = false;
    // Timer to link to the Bezier formual, Beginnning = 0, End = 1
    public float time = 0.0f;
    public float RotationSpeed;
    public float MinDistance;
    public float Distance;
    public bool hasAxe = true;
    public bool debounce = true;
    public float gunDelay;
    [Range (-10,10)]
    public float TimeReduction;
    [Range (0.1f , 100)]
    public float VelocidadeDeAjuste;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        Distance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, axe.transform.position);
        // When the user/player hits the mouse left button
        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1") && hasAxe == true && debounce == true)
        {
            ThrowAxe();
            debounce = false;
            Invoke("debouncer" , gunDelay);
        }

        // When the user/player hits the mouse right button
        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1") && hasAxe == false && debounce == true)
        {
            ReturnAxe();
            debounce = false;
            Invoke("debouncer" , gunDelay);
        }

        // If the axe is returning
        if(isReturning){
            // Returning calcs
            // Check if we haven't reached the end point, where time = 1




                if(time < 1.0f){
                // Update its position by using the Bezier formula based on the current time
                axe.position = getBQCPoint(time, old_pos, curve_point.position, target.position);
                // Reset its rotation (from current to the targets rotation) with 50 units/s
                if (Distance > MinDistance) {
                //axe.transform.localEulerAngles += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
                Debug.Log("Nao Esta Distancia");
                }

                if (Distance <= MinDistance) {
                axe.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(axe.transform.rotation, target.rotation,Time.deltaTime * (time * VelocidadeDeAjuste));
                axe.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
                Debug.Log("Em Distancia");
                }
                else
                {
                    axe.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;
                }

                // Increase our timer, if you want the axe to return faster, then increase "time" more
                // With something like:
                // time += Timde.deltaTime * 2;
                // It will return as twice as fast
                time += Time.deltaTime/TimeReduction;
            }else{
                // Otherwise, if it is 1 or more, we reached the target so reset
                ResetAxe();
            }
        }
    }

    // Throw axe
    void ThrowAxe(){
        // The axe isn't returning
        isReturning = false;
        hasAxe = false;
        // Deatach it form its parent
        axe.transform.parent = null;
        // Set isKinematic to false, so we can apply force to it
        axe.isKinematic = false;
        // Add force to the forward axis of the camera
        // We used TransformDirection to conver the axis from local to world
        axe.AddForce(Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * throwForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        // Add torque to the axe, to give it much cooler effect (rotating)
        axe.AddTorque(axe.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * RotationSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
        axe.transform.GetComponent<AxeWeapon>().Retornando = false;
    }

    // Return axe
    void ReturnAxe(){
        // We are returning the axe; so it is in its first point where time = 0
        time = 0.0f;
        // Save its last position to refer to it in the Bezier formula
        old_pos = axe.position;
        // Now we are returning the axe, to start the calculations in the Update method
        isReturning = true;
        // Reset its velocity
        axe.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        // Set isKinematic to true, so now we control its position directly without being affected by force
        axe.isKinematic = true;
        axe.AddTorque(axe.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * -1) * RotationSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
        axe.transform.GetComponent<AxeWeapon>().Retornando = true;
    }

    // Reset axe
    void ResetAxe(){
        // Axe has reached, so it is not returning anymore
        isReturning = false;
        // Attach back to its parent, in this case it will attach it to the player (or where you attached the script to)
        axe.transform.parent = transform;
        // Set its position to the target's
        axe.position = target.position;
        // Set its rotation to the target's
        axe.rotation = target.rotation;
        hasAxe = true;
        axe.transform.GetComponent<AxeWeapon>().Retornando = false;
    }

    // Bezier Quadratic Curve formula
    // Learn more:
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve
    Vector3 getBQCPoint(float t, Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2){
        // "t" is always between 0 and 1, so "u" is other side of t
        // If "t" is 1, then "u" is 0
        float u = 1 - t;
        // "t" square
        float tt = t * t;
        // "u" square
        float uu = u * u;
        // this is the formula in one line
        // (u^2 * p0) + (2 * u * t * p1) + (t^2 * p2)
        Vector3 p = (uu * p0) + (2
         * u * t * p1) + (tt * p2);
        return p;
    }

    void debouncer()
    {
      debounce = true;
    }
}


enter code here
```

I currently have this:

https://youtu.be/cEYYnGo-4dg

Comment: Why don't you animate the whole process?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over complicating things. the only variables you would need would be the return position(the players hand), how fast the axe should go, and the animator variable. And about the curve and the rotation, you can just do that with animation because it will clean up the code a bit more. and for where the player wants the axe to be thrown, you can make a raycast that checks if the axe is pointing at a suitable target. And to make sure the player can't just add a delay and modify it to fit your needs. Hope this helps! :D